# Canopy Python import PIL libjpeg not found

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, enthought, canopy

I am facing a problem with Canopy python and the Python Image Library.

I would like to use the _imaging library, but importing yields a libjpeg not found error

```
import _imaging
dlopen("/home/abcd/Canopy/C64/User/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so", 2);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: libjpeg.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm working on Fedora 19, and have ensured that (according to yum) libjpeg should be provided:

```
# yum provides libjpeg
libjpeg-turbo-1.2.90-2.fc19.i686 : A MMX/SSE2 accelerated library for manipulating JPEG image files
Repo        : fedora
Provides    : libjpeg = 6b-47.fc19
```

and

```
yum update
No packages marked for update
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: In canopy you have also the "package manager" wherein you can select the libjpeg7 library. It is not installed by the default installation. But (apparently) a requirement for this part of the PIL. After installation the problem was solved.

Comment: Note that Fedora provides `libjpeg-turbo 1.2`, rather than `libjpeg 7`, otherwise a system update of the library would have fixed the issue,